# How to to solve the problemThe POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel-9

I want to create CRUD on admin dashboard, but But when i click submit button, i got this error message "POST method is not supported for this route. Supported method: GET, HEAD."

**My View**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>Add Products
                        <a href="{{ url('admin/products') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-white float-end">BACK</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form action="{{ url('admin/products') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                                    data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab"
                                    aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="seotag-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                                    data-bs-target="#seotag-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab"
                                    aria-controls="seotag-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">SEO
                                    Tags</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="details-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                                    data-bs-target="#details-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab"
                                    aria-controls="details-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Details</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="image-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                                    data-bs-target="#image-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab"
                                    aria-controls="image-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Product Image</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade border p-3 show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">
                                <div class="md-3">
                                    <label>Product Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="md-3">
                                    <label>Product Slug</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="md-3">
                                    <label>Small Description (500 Words)</label>
                                    <textarea name="small_description" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="md-3">
                                    <label>Description</label>
                                    <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade border p-3" id="seotag-tab-pane" role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="profile-tab" tabindex="0">
                                <div class="md-3">
                                    <label>Meta Title</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="meta_title" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="md-3">
                                    <label>Meta Description</label>
                                    <textarea name="small_description" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="md-3">
                                    <label>Meta Keyword</label>
                                    <textarea name="meta_keyword" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade border p-3" id="details-tab-pane" role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="details-tab" tabindex="0">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="md-3">
                                            <label>Original Price</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="original_price" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="md-3">
                                            <label>Selling Price</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="selling_price" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="md-3">
                                            <label>Quantity</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="md-3">
                                            <label>Trending</label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="trending" style="width: 50px; height; 50px;" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="md-3">
                                            <label>Status</label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="status" style="width: 50px; height; 50px;" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade border p-3" id="image-tab-pane" role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="image-tab" tabindex="0">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label>Upload Product Images</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="image" multiple class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-white">Submit</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\ProductFormRequest;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $product = Product::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.products.index');
    }
    
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.products.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'require|string|min:5',
            'slug' => 'require|string|min:5',
            'small_description' => 'require|string',
            'description' => 'require|string',
            'original_price' => 'require|integer',
            'selling_price' => 'require|integer',
            // 'trending' => 'nullable',
            // 'status' => 'nullable',
            'meta_title' => 'require|string|max:255',
            'meta_keyword' => 'require|string',
            'meta_description' => 'require|string',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);

         // upload new image
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $image->storeAs('admin/products', $image->hashName());

        Product::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'slug' => $request->slug,
            'small_description' => $request->small_description,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'original_price' => $request->original_price,
            'selling_price' => $request->selling_price,
            'meta_title' => $request->meta_title,
            'meta_keyword' => $request->meta_keyword,
            'meta_description' => $request->meta_description,
            'image' => $image->hashName()
        ]);
        //redirect to index
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index')->with(['success' => 'Data Berhasil Disimpan!']);
    }
}
```

**My Route**

```
Route::controller(App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController::class)->group(function (){
        Route::get('/products','index');
        Route::get('/products/create','create');
        Route::post('/admin/products','store');
    });
```

I want to submit. But when I click on submit button, I got this error message "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc1sP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.

I had the same error also, try clearing the route cache and hopefully that will solve your problem.

Command:

```
php artisan route:cache
```